# Downcast IFile to File

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it safe to downcast an IFile to File?

```
File downCastedFile = (File) getSomeIFile();
```

Or should I choose one of the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812413/convert-ifile-to-file)?

Comment: The answers in the link are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll go with those. In my IDE, I didn't get any compilation errors, that's why I assumed that it might work.

Comment: Yes, it does compile because the compiler can't know for sure that the cast won't work. In practice it will always throw `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @StephenC The asker probably means `org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File`, not `java.io.File`.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Of course

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that if you cast a reference of interface type to any other type the compiler will blindly trust you.

During the runtime if indeed the reference points to an object of the type you are casting it to everything will go smoothly, otherwise the `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

For example, given that you have:

```
class FoodProcessor implements CoffeeExpress, Blender, Juicer{....}
```

then:

```
Object o = new FoodProcessor();
CoffeeExpress c = (CoffeeExpress)o;//fine
Blender b = (Blender)o;//fine
Juicer j = (Juicer)o;//fine
FoodProcessor f = (FoodProcessor)o;//fine
A a = new A();//where A does not implement any of CoffeeExpress, Blender and Juicer and does not derive from FoodProcessor
c = (CoffeeExpress)a;//ClassCastException
b = (Blender)a;//ClassCastException
j = (Juicer)a;//ClassCastException
f = (FoodProcessor)a;//ClassCastException
```

To answer your question you have to ask yourself: Does `getSomeIFile();` returns a value of type that is `File` or derives from `File`?